# CPT exam Quantitative aptitude exercise 8c

Tags: limits, continuity

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{6^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{6^n}\right]$$ is:

(a) $\frac15$

(b)$\frac16$

(c)$-\frac{1}{5}$

(d) none of these

According to book answer is (a). How?

Comment: What do you know about the sum of terms of a geometric sequence?

Comment: First of all it is not related to continuity, I know that the chapter's name is "limits and continuity" but it is just the "limits" part of it. And please add your own work, MSE, is not a website for homework questions. Add the confusions you face, what is your level etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric sequence, 
$$\frac{\frac16(1-\frac1{6^n})}{1-\frac16}$$ 
$$=\frac{6^n-1}{5.6^n}$$ 
Taking the limit, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}=\frac{6^n-1}{5.6^n}$$ 
$$\frac15\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{6^n-1}{6^n}$$ 
Which is, $$\bbox[black]{\Large\color{white}{=\frac{1}{5}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$S=\frac 16+\frac1{6^2}+ ...$$

We have
$$6S=1+\frac 16+\frac1{6^2}+ ...=1+?$$